# Why does Drush:migrate not generate config entities for separate content types?

Tags: 9, migrations, configuration

When using Drupal 9 with modules `migrate`, `migrate_drupal`, `migrate_upgrade` and `migrate_plus`, and calling `drush:migrate --configure-only` with a Drupal 7 source database

- I see migrations at `drush migrate-status`, also one for each content type, like `d7_node_complete:page`
- I see a lot of yamls appear after `drush config:export`, but none for content types
- I see configs appear in the ui at admin/config/development/configuration/single/export, but none for content types

I specifically want to migrate certain content types, so I was expecting to get their yamls (like in the example here https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/migrate-api/migrate-api-overview#s-highwater-marks ) and modify them.

Am I doing something wrong, or was I expecting something wrong ?